# validate file extention only if the file field is not empty using jquery validation plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to achieve that if file field is not empty then only validate other wise not on the update details form.

I am using following code of https://jqueryvalidation.org/ plugin :

```
 jQuery.validator.addMethod("filetype", function(value, element) {
    var types = ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png'],
        ext = value.replace(/.*[.]/, '').toLowerCase();

    if (types.indexOf(ext) !== -1) {
            //$("#city_banner-error").html('');
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("filetype", function(value, element) {
    var types = ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png'],
        ext = value.replace(/.*[.]/, '').toLowerCase();

    if (types.indexOf(ext) !== -1) {
            //$("#city_banner-error").html('');
        return true;
    }
    return false;
    },
  "Please select allowed file"
  );
  $('#frm').validate({
    rules:
    {
        file:
      {
        filetype: true
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Html

```
<form id="frm" name="frm">
  <input type="file" name="file" />
</form>
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cubttgow/3/)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to write any new rules.  Just use [the `extension` method](https://jqueryvalidation.org/extension-method/) built into the plugin.  It's part of [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/additional-methods.js).

```
$( "#myform" ).validate({
    rules: {
        field: {
            required: true,
            extension: "xls|csv"
        }
    }
});
```